# how do i split data fields into two separate columns in .xls files

Tags: c#, asp.net, binary, xls

I have the following of codes to write data in `.xls` files. 
How do I separate this two data fields and store in different columns in the `.xls` file?

```
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data"]);
Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["data2"]);
```

Please help!

Comment: just print as html table.

Comment: i want to download these info as excel files

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have `DataTable` named `dt` then

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table><tr>");

foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<th>{0}</th>", dc.ColumnName);
}

sb.Append("</tr>");

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.Append("<tr>");

    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        sb.AppendFormat("<td>{0}</td>", row[dc]);

    sb.Append("</tr>");
}

sb.Append("</table>");

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=MyFiles.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Write(sb.ToString())
```

Comment: what if im handling with data of varbinary(max)?